# How to replace all matching regex of a sting in PHP

Tags: php, regex

sorry for not beeing able to put the title exactly what my question, I can't find a way to ask it.

So im trying to replace all `&#39;` in a text inside and replace it for `'` in php

I have a variable `$desc = "he&#39;s such a good person and he&#39;ll be very successfull";`

and I'm trying to do the following

```
$desc = str_replace("&#39;","'",$desc);
```

But no success is there a way to use regex in `str_replace`?

Yes it looks to be fine now... for some reason.

Is there a way to use regex for it?

for example to remove html tags from the text?

`$desc = "<strong> he&#39;s such a good person </strong> <br /> he&#39;ll be very successfull";`

`$desc = str_replace("<*>"," ",$desc);`

Comment: It is working fine. try this https://eval.in/800942

Comment: It works fine...?

Comment: You must have used `htmlentities` somewhere before the current line. Use `html_entity_decode` to decode the entities to their literal representations.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use the correct PHP function to do this job, so please take a look at : `preg_replace` doc.

In your case, you would like to use like this :

```
preg_replace('/&#39;/', "'", $desc);
```

Take a look at this execution:
https://eval.in/800948

Comment: Can this be used for an example `preg_replace('<*>', " ", $desc);`?

Comment: of course @JuanfriLira you can use it like this : `preg_replace('/\<.*\>/', "<better>", $desc);` to replace text between "<" and ">".

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a regex because this is a lot simpler way to do it

```
$desc = "he&#39;s such a good person and he&#39;ll be very successfull";

$new = str_replace('&#39;', "'", $desc);
echo $new;
```

RESULT:

```
he's such a good person and he'll be very successfull
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex as it will be more complex 
use

```
$desc = "he&#39;s such a good person and he&#39;ll be very       successfull";
$desc = str_replace("&#39;","'",$desc);
echo "after replace :"." ".$desc;
```

it is more simpler :)